# My depth map (displace/texture) and image (on plane) aren't lining up?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor, displacement, texture-coordinates, depth-map

Super easy solution im sure but i just can't seem to figure it out.

Im attempting a Parallax effect and am using a depth map as texture for a displacement modifier however the displacement is rotated and not in line with the image.

Im intending to use this method a lot so i would hope there's a way i can just import the image and depth map and it lines up perfectly rather than me having to line it up every time.

This is what im trying to create:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ax3REy8vSzU

The source image and depth map are the same dimensions.

Thanks!

project file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z9vGsCSCRZx-VwQ1d8P1hNlgx2sPcNa4/view?usp=share_link

[image: depth map]

[image: what happening]

Answer (score 0):

change to UV in displace modifier (default is local)

[image: displace UV]